# Ladies' Cycling Shoe Sizes/Fits

Tags: bike-fit, shoes, women-specific

I am interested to know what differences there are between brands of women's cycling shoes, specifically, who makes shoes in larger or smaller sizes as well as who makes shoes for narrow feet or for wider feet.

I don't need product recommendations, rather an idea of which companies make shoes to fit different feet.

Comment: An answer to this will depend where in the world you are. Really the only answer is to try out shoes available at retail locations in your area, although you could ask a cycling forum for recommendation for a product  for your specific need (which as you realize is off-topic here).

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go to a (bigger) bike store and try different brands.

Are you looking for women shoes to fit smaller feet or bigger feet?

Depending on what you are looking for, sometimes getting a man's shoe might be better (for wider/bigger feet)

If you have weird feet, you should look into custom made/fitted shoes.